# matrix manipulation on 2 rectangles

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a rectangle of fixed size and another rectangle inside it,
I need to transform the **black** rectangle so that the the only thing that will be seen inside the **red** rectangle will be the **blue** rectangle.

[image]

What I need to do is simulate zooming.
I have a window of fixed size that will not change, inside I have an image that is initially the same size as the window.
Now, I create a rectangle inside the window and want to zoom to it that means that this rectangle will need to be the size of the window.
But the only way to do it is by *resizing the image* in a way that the only thing I can see from that image is the rectangle.
So in the image above - the red square is the window, the black squarer is the image, and the blue rectangle is the rectangle of the zoom.
I hope that makes the question clearer.

EDIT:
I am given coordinates(x,y,width,height) of the all the rectangles.
The window's coordinates can't change and the upper left corner is (0,0).
The image starts at (0,0) and has the same width and height of the window, but its coordinates(x,y,width,height) all can change(x,y can be negative).
The rectangle starts at (x,y) where x < window width and y < window height.

Thanks

Comment: Do the rectangles necessarily have the same center?

Comment: No, also I edited the question and added more information.

Comment: Do the rectangles necessarily have the same proportions?  That is, are the vertical and horizontal stretch always the same?

Comment: Also no, but if it will be easier to solve this then it could be possible.

Comment: It's not that much of a difference, really

Comment: Last question: how is the image stored?  Can you check for the color of a given pixel?

Comment: Well I can but I don't see how it is relevant. I have the dimensions of the window, image and rectangle and I just need in someway to resize the image so the rectangle would fit the window. The rectangle is virtual - when you resize the image the rectangle is resized too.

Comment: So the question is how do you want us to "describe" the rectangle? Are there some coordinates we can use?  Can we say, for example, that we have the coordinates of the corners of the big rectangle and of the smaller one?

Comment: Yes of course, sorry for not being clear enough. 
The coordinates of the window and initial image are (0,0) and have a known height and width.
The coordinates of rectangle start in (x,y) where $0<x<window width$ and $0<y<windowheight$ and also have a known height and width: $0<rectangle width<window width$ and $0<rectangle height<window height$